# Exporting grid vector from QGIS to KML gives wrong coordinates

Tags: qgis, vector, coordinates, kml, grids-graticules

A grid vector was created over the map layer (EPSG:32636) and saved as with CSR EPSG:32636.

Then when I export it as KML, it the grid appears in a different country (Congo rather than Lebanon).

- I tried to export the KML under different CSR (EPSG:4326, 3857 or 32636): same problem
- I tried to create columns of latitude/longitude using $x and $y for each polygon of the grid but the columns remain NULL

Here is the link to the shapefile of the grid vector.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z5vWO-f0cmdY0FGD1xh24voFsT3OhmBo?usp=sharing

Does anyone have an idea? I am sure there is something wrong with the CSR and I tried everything that I knew so far.

Comment: KML can only be exported to 4326. How did you create the grid? To what data type did you save it? Can you provide data examples?

Comment: Ok, Thanks Erik. I didn't know kml were only in 4326. I created the grid using the vector tools of QGIS (Create grid vector) and i saved it into ESRI shp file. I added the link to the file in the post.

Comment: What extent/bounding box did you set for the grid you created? Also, what happens if you load the kml back into QGIS?

Comment: I used extent of the target layer, which is the map of two districts. Yes, it works perfectly when I load it back to QGIS.

Comment: I suggest you give permission to access the shape file?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. It's fixed now.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18hdQ3Vkd2TnTy8RSQRXVW8f1C0i2wzlK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The shapefile is just west of Lake Albert in Kongo. So, the export to kml works fine - you made an error while creating the grid.

Comment: Erik, thank you so much. I went back to the file downloaded from Diva and it is good. Therefore the problem is due from an error during the grid creation. I can't explain why it appears in Congo. I am very grateful though for your help!